# Not capturing last group in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I'm using JavaScript regex to split up multiple commands using the separators (&&, ;, |) to determine the boundries of commands. This works well for all except the last command. As a hack I can add a new line to the end of the commands to capture the last group. Here is the code.

```js
const regex = /(.*?)(&&|\||;|\r?\n)/gm
// The EOL is a hack to capture the last command
const test = 'read -p test TEST && echo | ls -lh ~/bin; test | echo\n'
let m

while ((m = regex.exec(test)) !== null) {
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match.trim()}`)
  })
}
```

Is there a way to change the regex so that it will capture the last group without the hack?

Comment: Try `(.+?)(&&|\||;|$)` and repeat 1+ times any  char to prevent matching an empty string.

Comment: Why not just split the string at all separators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should fix your problem: `/(.*?)(&&|\||;|\r|$)/gm`
Adding the `$` makes it match "line endings" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `(.+?)(&&|\||;|$)` using `$` to assert the end of the line and use `.+?` to match any char except a newline 1 or more times to prevent matching an empty string.

If you also want to match a comma you could add that to your alternation.

Note that you are using 2 capturing groups. If you are not using the data from group 2 you could make it non capturing instead `(?:`

```js
const regex = /(.+?)(&&|\||;|$)/gm;
const test = 'read -p test TEST && echo | ls -lh ~/bin; test | echo\n';
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(test)) !== null) {
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match.trim()}`)
  })
}
```